# JPA Query Exception to fetch data with join

Tags: java, jpa

Dao class

```
@Query("select pt from com.ctpm.rrh.basket.model.user.User as u  inner join u.userPaymentTransaction as pt where u = ?")
    List<UserPaymentTransaction> findPaymentTransactionforUser(User user);
```

QueryException on console

> ` org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userPaymentTransaction of: com.ctpm.rrh.basket.model.user.User [select pt from com.ctpm.rrh.basket.model.user.User as u  inner join u.userPaymentTransaction as pt where u = ?]

UserPaymentTransaction class has

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Money amount;

    private String description;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    User owningUser;

    private Date transactionDate;
```

Please help

Comment: Where is the code causing this `Exception` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your query should be something like this:-

```
@Query("select pt from UserPaymentTransaction pt where pt.owningUser = ?1")
```

Comment: @ RJ  Ok thanks if i need list of  UserPaymentTransaction than which query should i use ?

Comment: This will give a list of `UserPaymentTransaction`, where all the `UserPaymentTransaction.user = userYouHaveSet`.

Comment: @RJ now i changed question please check

Comment: @krishan - Since its a one-one mapping, the list will have only 1 element. Even if you go the other way around, you'll get just 1 result for a particular user. That's essentially `One-One` for you!

Comment: @RJ according to you which query is working for list of UserPaymentTransaction based on owningUser id ?

Comment: List of `UserPaymentTransaction` based on what?!

Comment: UserPaymentTransaction based on owningUser

Comment: The query I've given, will fetch a list of `UserPaymentTransaction` based on the `owningUser`.

Comment: UserPaymentTransaction is not mapped [select pt from UserPaymentTransaction pt where pt.owningUser = ?1]